# ConstraintLayout intermittent layout failure

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view, android-constraintlayout

`ConstraintLayout` intermittently fails to layout correctly when a view is set from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` shortly after an activity is resumed:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        text1.text = ""
        text1.visibility = View.GONE

        text2.text = ""
        text2.visibility = View.GONE

        text1.postDelayed({
                    text1.text = "Hello"
                    text1.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    text2.text = "World"
                    text2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }, 100
        )
    }
```

[Full source code here](https://github.com/alexbirkett/ConstraintLayoutBug)

Instrumenting the `TextView` class reveals that the `TextView` instances are measured correctly but their width is set to 0 when they are laid out.

I wonder if the `ConstraintLayout` `LinearSystem` is non-deterministic. Are there maps that are iterated over where the iteration order is undefined? (I've seen this with Cassowary)

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this in a project that doesn't use kotlin? I have not been able to, but it could be device-specific.

Comment: No I've not tried without Kotlin. I'd be extremely surprised if it was something do with the Kotlin language. Did you try the project here? https://github.com/alexbirkett/ConstraintLayoutBug It seems easiest to reproduce on older slower phones. I used a Samsung Galaxy S3 in the video

Comment: I downloaded it, but I don't have the Android Studio 3 beta installed. Of course I could install it or try to get the project working with a different gradle plugin but that's just enough of an obstacle for me to not want to bother. Plus if I change the plugin and then I can't reproduce it, is that really useful info?

Comment: Issue raised here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65613481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the ConstraintLayout fixed in `constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta2` https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65613481

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to your statement in [github page](https://github.com/alexbirkett/ConstraintLayoutBug):

> **ConstraintLayout** intermittently fails to layout correctly when a view is set from **GONE** to **VISIBLE** shortly after an activity is resumed

I've checked out your project and changed 100ms to 1000ms.
Here's the output:

[image]

It seems to me, that you expect that the moment you perform `textview.setVisibility(View.GONE)` you expect the view to be not visible. That's not the way android works. You are merely posting an event to the `MessageQueue` that would be handled later by `Looper`, and this 100ms is not enough for human eye to see those changes happening.

Comment: The views are being set to visible, not invisible, after 100ms but sometimes they don't appear. I've not tried reproducing with an emulator but it happens on slower devices e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: `The views are being set to visible, not invisible` I'm talking about this line `text1.visibility = View.GONE`. `it happens on slower devices` which means 100ms is not enough.

Comment: It should be possible to set visibility from GONE to VISIBLE without waiting for an arbitrary amount of time even if layout happens asynchronously

Comment: Just to double check I tested with a RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout but I can't reproduce the bug.